# Is Videne effective as a non-rinse santizer?

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer, starsan

In nearly all the online videos from experienced homebrewers, they use Star San as a non-rinse sanitizer. However in the UK it is not widely available (only one site has it online and it is not available in any of my LHBS).

I did a quick search for alternatives and found mention of using Videne (an antiseptic solution used in medical surgeries). Has anybody used this in brewing? and is it as effective as Star San (i.e. effective sanisting, non-rinse, short contact time, no undesirable taste)?

Comment: Are there no other brands available there? I've always had good luck with 1-Step (easy to find anywhere around me), but I don't know if it's widely distributed in the UK.

Comment: A quick search for 1-Step (or One-Step) doesn't seem to yield results in the UK

Comment: one step is a cleanser and not a sanitizer FYI.  They really need to change the name or advertise it more appropriately.  While many brewers seem to get buy using it as a sanitizer, I do know a growing # of brewers that have been having problems with contamination.

Comment: Here's a couple of links to sites in the UK selling StarSan http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Five_Star_Star_San_16oz_454g.html http://www.themaltmiller.co.uk/index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=402

Comment: An alternative to one-step is OxiClean, or any oxygen-based cleaner you can get from the supermarket (e.g. Vanish) - they often carry 2-for-1 deals. Just make sure it's unscented. Although they are not classified as sanitizers, they can do a good enough job if used with sufficient concentration, and with a 5 minute contact time. I used it for sanitizing clean bottles before I got hold of StarSan. http://www.lakeland.co.uk/20950/Oxi-Clean

Comment: As another possible option, I've been using iodophor for no-rinse sanitizer and haven't had any infections after many a brew.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it myself, but found that some high ranking members over at [www.thehomebrewforum.co.uk](http://www.thehomebrewforum.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=313) use it. They say they got it at the Pharmacist at ASDA for about £4.50 for a 500ml bottle. This is then diluted to 2.5ml in 2000ml water, so it's going to last a while!

1.25ml/l is the usual concentration. 2.5ml/l is the maximum no-rinse concentration.

[brewuk.co.uk](http://www.brewuk.co.uk/forum/topic/vidine) has this advice:

> I switched to videne many brews ago, using 1.25-1.5ml per litre of
>   water to get a no-rinse solution.
>
> **How do I use it?**
>
> I use 500ml in a spray bottle to brew ( Great for spraying up taps, into tubes and bottles, for other things like FV’s I
>   pour a small amount into it and rotate the FV, then a quick spray and
>   tip out)
>
> **make sure everything is properly cleaned & rinsed with hot water**
>   first.
>
> 0.75ml per half a litre and also add a 0.5 teaspoon (2.5gms) of citric acid to increases and prolongs its effectiveness. Best use
>   filtered/treated/bottle water as chlorine and water hardness can
>   effect how long the solution lasts.
>
> You can get citric acid from BrewUK, it looks a bit like table sugar,
>   but it tastes foul if used in tea (trust me on that one I’ve made the
>   mistake)!
>
> The solution is the colour of cold tea. Over time as it loses its
>   sterilizing potency as it looses its sterilizing effect it loses its
>   colour. Also best stored out of light!